# How to get only first character match with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a string in JavaScript using RegEX.

**This is the example string:**

```
REQUEST : LOREMLOREM : LOREM2LOREM2
```

**Is it possible to split it into:**

```
[REQUEST , LOREMLOREM : LOREM2LOREM2]
```

I've tried using `/:?/g`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you plz try  /([A-Z])\w+/g

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a regex, you could split on a colon and then use a combination of [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to remove and return the first item from the array and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to concatenate the remaining items using a colon:

```js
let str = "REQUEST : LOREMLOREM : LOREM2LOREM2";
$parts = str.split(':');
[a, b] = [$parts.shift().trim(), $parts.join(':').trim()];
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
var parts = str.match(/([^:]*)\s*:\s*(.*)/).slice(1)
```

This will match the whole string and extract the two desired parts. The `slice` operation makes the result a plain array and removes the whole string from the results.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/6S9dCw/1
is it possible to get the REQUEST SEND MAIL as the first array and the rest of the string splitted by the first " : " as the second array

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the Global modifier **'g'** in the end and the **'?'** Quantifier. Without these the expression will return the first match only.

Your new RegEx will be **/:/**

For Testing your regular expressions go to **https://regex101.com/r/11VFJ8/2**

Comment: its working in regex101 but not working when im working with my code

Comment: for example i tried to print the second array and it still showing

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/6S9dCw/1 
the number is located at the 2nd array

Comment: @JohannesSandjaja Can you try using this RegEx `/:(.+)/` It selects the second part of the text completely. Link : https://regex101.com/r/6S9dCw/2